# How can I validate, if the email is from the administrator, and redirect it to a special window

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework

I want that when entering the mail, a specific window redirects it, and when it is a normal user to another. How can i do it? Since at the time of validation it always pulls me to the same point whether I am an administrator or not.

I work using Angular, Ionic, and as a FireBase database

This is the HTML

```
    <ion-content padding class="form-content">
    <form class="form" [formGroup]="validations_form" (ngSubmit)="tryLogin(validations_form.value)">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label position="floating" color="primary">Email</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" formControlName="email"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <div class="validation-errors">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let validation of validation_messages.email">
        <div class="error-message" *ngIf="validations_form.get('email').hasError(validation.type) && (validations_form.get('email').dirty || validations_form.get('email').touched)">
          {{ validation.message }}
        </div>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label position="floating" color="primary">Password</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="password" formControlName="password"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <div class="validation-errors">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let validation of validation_messages.password">
        <div class="error-message" *ngIf="validations_form.get('password').hasError(validation.type) && (validations_form.get('password').dirty || validations_form.get('password').touched)">
          {{ validation.message }}
        </div>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
    <ion-button class="submit-btn" expand="block" type="submit" [disabled]="!validations_form.valid">Log In</ion-button>
    <label class="error-message">{{errorMessage}}</label>
  </form>
<p class="go-to-register">
No account yet? <a (click)="goRegisterPage()">Create an account.</a>
  </p>
</ion-content>
```

This is the ts

```
    export class LoginPage implements OnInit {
    validations_form: FormGroup;
     errorMessage: string = '';

  validation_messages = {
   'email': [
     { type: 'required', message: 'Email is required.' },
     { type: 'pattern', message: 'Please enter a valid email.' }
   ],
   'password': [
     { type: 'required', message: 'Password is required.' },
     { type: 'minlength', message: 'Password must be at least 5 characters long.' }
   ]
 };

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private router: Router
  ) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.validations_form = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$')
      ])),
      password: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([
        Validators.minLength(5),
        Validators.required
      ])),
    });
  }
  tryLogin(value){
    this.authService.doLogin(value)
    .then(res => {
      this.router.navigate(["/home"]);
    }, err => {
      this.errorMessage = err.message;
      console.log(err)
    })
  }
  goRegisterPage(){
    this.router.navigate(["/register"]);
  }
}
```

Any help, I will greatly appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build a guard that, on activation, returns the right destination. So you always send the logged user to a common route, but the activation guard redirect's it if necessary. An example routing config:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '/common-users-route',
    component: CommonUsersComponent,
    canActivate: [CommonUsersRouteGuard]
  },
  {
    path: '/administrator-route',
    component: AdministratorComponent,
    canActivate: [AdministratorRouteGuard]
  },
]
```

#### CommonUsersRouteGuard:

```js
constructor(private _router: Router, private _userService: UserService) {}

canActivate(
  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot
): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | UrlTree | boolean {

  if(this._userService.isAdministrator()) {
    return this._router.parseUrl('/administrator-route');
  }

  return true;
}
```

#### AdministratorRouteGuard:

```js
constructor(private _router: Router, private _userService: UserService) {}

canActivate(
  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot
): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | UrlTree | boolean {

  if(this._userService.isAdministrator()) {
    return true;
  }

  return this._router.parseUrl('/common-users-route');
}
```

Comment: ¡Woow! Thank you so much, I hadn't thought about the Guards.
Many thanks!